# Api Platform & JWT token : I can authenticate but all newt=xt request are 401

Tags: api-platform.com, jwt

I have a client that authenticates to API platform, token is generated and send back to client. Client embed the token in the requests header, but still have a 401 error return from the server : JWT not found. It is in the header thougth (verified with FIrefox)

Have you already had this issue ? (further posts without response).
Is there a possibility Apache or firewall blocks the token ?

How can I find the issue source?

NB: the excat same config was working well on dev server in local. Just clone the git to server and and made acomposer made a composer install. I tried to reinstall lexik, regenrate the .pem.... nothing work

Thank you for your help

Comment: How did you embed your token in your client request ? Have you tried on Nelmio API documentation page ?

Comment: did you take [apache configuration](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#important-note-for-apache-users) in consideration ?